# Dynamic pages in jquery mobile application

Tags: cordova, jquery-mobile

I have a jquery mobile application running with PhoneGap.
The whole application is about 10 pages and they are all written in one index.html.
The first three pages are a setup wizard, which means that after the user has completed the wizard they should be removed from the application ( I don't want to allow to user to go back into the wizard once he is done ).
In my main.js I am checking whether the user is registered and jumping directly to page number 4 after the application has loaded using changePage()
The problem is after the wizard or after the application has loaded, the user can go back either to the wizard pages, or to the first wizard page as this is the first page of the application.

I want to start from page 1 or page 4 and not allow going back in these cases.

Should I reload the application, or remove the pages? What is the best way to achieve this functionality.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this

```
$( window ).on( "navigate", function( event, data ){
    if( data.state.direction == "back" ) {
       // Make use of the directional information
    }
}
```

You have to bind on the navigate event and if you are on the 4th page just use `preventDefault` and do what you want.